File path not recognized to publish RMarkdown with embedded Shiny on shinyapps.io
I have an RMarkdown html document in RStudio, where I am trying to insert a shiny app which deploys and runs ok when I click on "Run Document", but when I try to publish it from here to shinyapps.io, it throws an error in the browser, and in the log I can see this: Error in shinyAppDir: No Shiny application exists at the path "C:/Users/xiriu/Documents/R/WorkD/shiny/in_qks"
This is the related code:
title:
author:
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny


  shinyAppDir("C:/Users/xiriu/Documents/R/WorkD/shiny/in_qks",
            options = list(width = "100%", height = 700))

The RStudio default directory is 'WorkD'
I have tried placing the app.R, the data file, and the RMarkdown in the default directory as well, with same results. I have also searched for some similar posts here in stackoverflow.
What am I missing here to get the directory above recognized to publish this RMarkdown document with embedded shiny? Thank you.

You need to use relative paths i.e. not C:/ because that path won't exist once it is deployed. shinyapps.io runs on Ubuntu and the C:/ doesn't even exist. shinyAppDir("shiny/in_qks") should fix it, assuming that you are deploying the contents of WorkD and that shiny/in_qks contains the app.R / server.R.

Thank you for your answer. However, the app.R file contains both the ui and server so, should I split the app.R in two files and keep the ui.R in my default directory 'WorkD' while the server.R remains in the 'shiny/in_qks' subdirectory? When I used the relative path didn't work either for the app.R (ui + server).

both the UI and server functions in the app.R is fine. If it is still not working, please provide a more complete example of how your files and folders are arranged and ideally a full minimal reproducible example.

This is the RMarkdown file:
title:
author:
date: "r Sys.Date()"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
shinyAppDir(".",
#  system.file("examples/06_tabsets", package = "shiny"),
          options = list(width = "100%", height = 500))

This is a reproducible example that automatically loads when choosing: File > New File > R Markdown >Shiny > Shiny Document, which runs and deploys ok.
I copied the app.R inside the shiny >examples/06_tabsets to my work directory, replaced the app. dir with "." -And I got the same error as before.
